# OnClickListener in Electron

Tags: javascript, click, electron, listener, dom-events

What am I doing wrong?
If I select the same element from Console and add a click listener… it works… however, this code doesn't work

```
const Template = require('./Template')
const mustache = require('mustache')
const DOMHelper = require('./DOMHelper')

class SymbolDefiner extends Template {
  constructor (key, data) {
    super(key)
    this._data = data
  }

  render () {
    super.render(arguments)
    const parent = this._parent
    const props = this._props
    const eventListener = this._listener

    const addSymbol = DOMHelper.createElement('button.btn.btn-primary', parent)
    const btnText = document.createTextNode('Add Symbol')
    addSymbol.appendChild(btnText)

    console.log(addSymbol) // this log succeeds
    addSymbol.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('xx')
    })
  }
}

module.exports = SymbolDefiner
```

The DOMHelper is just an easy function to add elements into the DOM by using very simple 'div#id.class-1.class-2' string.
Here is the code for DOMHelper:

```
const obj = {}

obj.createElement = function (selector, parent, props) {
    const details = selector.split('#')
    let eleName, eleId, classList
    if (details.length > 1) {
        // id is present
        eleName = details[0]
        const attribs = details[1].split('.')
        eleId = attribs.shift()
        classList = attribs
    } else {
        const attribs = details[0].split('.')
        eleName = attribs.shift()
        classList = attribs
    }

    const element = document.createElement(eleName)
    element.setAttribute('id', eleId || '')
    for (var i in classList) {
        element.classList.add(classList[i])
    }

    if (props) {
        for (var key in props) {
            element.setAttribute(key, props[key])
        }
    }

    if (parent) {
        parent.appendChild(element)
    }

    return element
}

module.exports = obj
```

Comment: _I'm not 100% sure but I have never seen a **click** magic string for the event I am aware of **onclick** you can [view the list here for native web browser events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) unless electron added a **click** you should change `ddSymbol.addEventListener('click', function () {` to `ddSymbol.addEventListener('onclick', function () {`_ edit: nvm forgot the event is different than the string magic.

Comment: I just tried out your code via web browser and it works flawlessly. Are there any console errors ?

Comment: No console errors! :(

Comment: can you try this with a custom element on the dom already added rather then having the generator doing it and then grab the element handler via document.getElementById('idname') and then adding an event listener onto that button my suspicion is that somehow in electron you don't have access that element once you have created it.

Comment: Thanks Andrei! I tried that too… didn't work

Comment: I realize that any HTML Element I create dynamically… has trouble listening to events…

Any thoughts would help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the index.html page I added all the code to the script, this is based off of a blank electron quick getting start CLI from [here](https://github.com/electron/electron)

the only things I changed was I didn't separate out the DOMHelper, I just added it inline and I use `obj.createElement()` directly. It worked perfectly, so everything you have written is correct. The only possible thing might be checking every reference of the import **require('./renderer.js')** but most likely not since the file itself is blank for me.

so your code is all golden hopefully this helps where to look

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
  We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>, Chromium
  <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>, and Electron
  <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  <div id="parentNode"></div>
</body>

<script>
  // You can also require other files to run in this process
  require('./renderer.js')
  var obj = {};
  obj.createElement = function(selector, parent, props) {
    const details = selector.split('#')
    let eleName, eleId, classList
    if (details.length > 1) {
      // id is present
      eleName = details[0]
      const attribs = details[1].split('.')
      eleId = attribs.shift()
      classList = attribs
    } else {
      const attribs = details[0].split('.')
      eleName = attribs.shift()
      classList = attribs
    }

    const element = document.createElement(eleName)
    element.setAttribute('id', eleId || '')
    for (var i in classList) {
      element.classList.add(classList[i])
    }

    if (props) {
      for (var key in props) {
        element.setAttribute(key, props[key])
      }
    }

    if (parent) {
      parent.appendChild(element)
    }

    return element
  }

  var parent = document.getElementById('parentNode');
  const addSymbol = obj.createElement('button.btn.btn-primary', parent)
  const btnText = document.createTextNode('Add Symbol')
  addSymbol.appendChild(btnText)

  console.log(addSymbol) // this log succeeds
  addSymbol.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('xx')
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Andrei…Thanks for all!

This is interesting…
When I remove `.addEventListener` and replace it with '.onclick = ' it works… But only the file where I create the DOMElement… Still don't understand the problem, but it works… thanks a lo!

Comment: np, if you ever figure it out add an answer as it would be interesting to find out eventually